# How do I localize password validation in C#?

Tags: c#, localization, special-characters

I am trying to localize an existing app that has the following logic that tries to validate a password text box.  I'm assuming that this will not work with languages with special characters that the user could type in the text box.  Am I correct?  I don't think that we want to restrict the user from typing non-English-type characters (i.e. arabic, chinese, etc.).  Or, is there something I'm not understanding?

```
Regex ValidHex =
   new Regex("[A-Za-z1234567890_-]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (!ValidHex.IsMatch(e.Text))
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do like this to support unicode characters:

```
[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+
```

As a side note: is there any specific reason you need to limit what characters are allowed?

Comment: Exactly, if the user wants to add weird codes for security, why prevent that?

Comment: Agreed; there is never ever a good reason to limit (or even require) certain combinations of characters in passwords, for your users.

Answer (score 7):

Don't store passwords!

Hash the password using a [cryptographic hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) and compare that.

Comment: @Ben S: where in the question is password storage mentioned?

Comment: Good advice in general, but also completely orthogonal to the question asked. He didn't say he was storing passwords, nor does his code snippet imply that he is.

Comment: @Ben S: I'm with Fredrik - he's just trying to strengthen passwords, there's no storage mentioned.

Comment: @Frederik: that would be in the last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

That regular expression isn't a particularly good one, it restricts the users options and doesn't enforce anything (the passwords 'a' and 'aaaaaaa' would pass). The name suggests it was adopted from an expression that validated Hex numbers. You would at least have to add a minimum Length condition (in the reg ex or as e.Text.Length > 8).

A more sensible expression would validate that at least 1 char form several groups was used, I dug up this:  `@"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\W)"`  [See here](http://www.zorched.net/2009/05/08/password-strength-validation-with-regular-expressions/).
Again, add a minimum length check.

This example does not address the problem of localization, It allows non-latin characters only through the '.' and does not consider them satisfying the [a-z] or [A-Z] requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using \w instead of A-za-z? I'm betting that will get around localization issues.